# Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: No setups configured?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have the following xunit test using `Moq`.

```
[Fact]
public void Presenter_Filter_ShouldFilterViewSearchList()
{
    var mockView = Mock.Get(mockSearchView);
    mockView.Setup(v => v.Ids).Returns("123");
    presenter.Filter();
    var mockRepo = Mock.Get(mockSearchRepository);
    Filter filter = new Filter { Ids = new List<string> { "123" } };
    mockRepo.Verify(r => r.GetSearchItems(5000, filter), Times.Once);
}
```

And the test failed with the following messages.

```
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: 
    r => r.GetSearchItems(5000, Filter)
No setups configured.
    
Performed invocations: 
ISearchRepository.GetSearchItems(5000)
ISearchRepository.GetSearchItems(5000, Filter)
```

The following is the tested function. And `ISearchRepository.GetSearchItems(5000, Filter)` is called?

```
public void Filter()
{
    var filter = new Filter {
        Name = _view.Name,
        Ids = _view.Ids?.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList(),
        Countries = _view.Countries?.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList(),
        Region = _view.Region,
    };
    _repository.GetSearchItems(5000, filter);
}
```

Comment: Where are you actually letting the system under test use the mock repository you created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is creating its own filter:

```
var filter = new Filter {
    Name = _view.Name,
    Ids = _view.Ids?.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList(),
    Countries = _view.Countries?.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList(),
    Region = _view.Region,
};
```

You are setting up a test with a different instance of the filter:

```
Filter filter = new Filter { Ids = new List<string> { "123" } };
mockRepo.Verify(r => r.GetSearchItems(5000, filter), Times.Once);
```

If you wish to test the call, the object passed must be the same object.

Otherwise, configure it to use any `Filter` object for the call:

```
 mockRepo.Verify(r => r.GetSearchItems(5000, It.IsAny<Filter>()), Times.Once);
```

Or pass the filter as an argument to the function:

```
public void Filter(Filter filter) 
{
    _repository.GetSearchItems(5000, filter);
}
```